# ProductDetails.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images')

Tags: reactjs, carousel

ProductDetails.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images')  
            {product.images && product.images.map((item, i) => (
                    
                  ))}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Missing information to be able to answer properly... But usually this error is given when the object in the next top level is `undefined`, in this example, `product` is `undefined`. If it's expected to be empty in certain situations, use optional chain to prevent the error.

```
product?.images?.map((item, i) => ( ))
```